# Combobox DropDown close transition like "Store" App

Tags: windows-8, combobox, microsoft-metro

I want to make the `combobox` like Windows `Store` app. When `dropdown` of the combobox is closed, comboboxitem will move to the combobox like it's walking to combobox. It's very `smooth`.

I placed a simple comboBox but it flickers when its drop down closes. Its not smooth. How to make it smooth?